# Display items in dropdown list and selected items box via the same binding using only XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, itemscontrol

I'm sure that someone will jump all over this as being answered somewhere else but I claim I have followed every relevant link on this site (and elsewhere) and tried all possible combinations of ItemTemplate, ComboBoxItem, ItemContainerStyle, DisplayMemberPath, SelectedItem, SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue and for the life of me I can't get this to work as desired.

I simply want to define a list of ContentControl object (using x:Array) in XAML resources used as an ItemsSource for a ComboBox. This list contains 2 elements whose Content property is set to a Grid control - also defined in the resources. Each item also has the Tag property set to a string that functions as the name or description of the content.

Very simply: I want the string in the Tag property to be displayed in the selected item portion of the ComboBox and as the list of selectable items in the dropdown portion of the ComboBox.

If I set DisplayMemberPath="Tag", then the dropdown portion works as desired but nothing is displayed in the selected item portion of the ComboBox. I'm sure that proper use of SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue is the key, but I simply can't get it to work.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Key="Fluidics" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="134"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Cartridge:" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="26" Width="62"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Cartridges}"
                            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCartridgeIndex, FallbackValue=0}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCartridge}"
                            Margin="0,5,0,0" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Config.FriendlyName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <views:FluidicsExperimentParamsView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding FluidicsExperimentParams}" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Key="Data acquisition" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="157"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="87"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Camera line:" />
        <ComboBox 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ImageDataAcquisitionParams}"
                            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCameraLine}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImageDataAcquisitionParams}"/>
        <data:ImageDataAcquisitionView
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            DataContext="{Binding ImageDataAcquisition}" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
    <x:Array x:Key="ControlActivities" Type="ContentControl">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Fluidics}}" Tag="Fluidics" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data acquisition}}" Tag="Data acquisition"/>
    </x:Array>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

...

```
<ComboBox Name="ControlActivityComboBox" 
          MinWidth="150" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ControlActivities}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActivity}"
          SelectedValuePath="Tag"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedActivity.Tag}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Tag"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          SelectedIndex="0">
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: `Very simply: I want the string in the Tag property to be displayed in the selected item portion of the ComboBox and as the list of selectable items in the dropdown portion of the ComboBox.`  umm what do you mean **and as the list**? do you want to **add** "Fluidics" to combo box items source? or do you want a list to be added to the list? why so complicated?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make this more simple. x:Array ControlActivities **is** the observable collection used as the ItemsSource for the ComboBox. That works correctly. When I click on the text box portion of the ComboBox, using DisplayMemberPath="Tag", items "Fluidics" and "Data acquisition" appear in the dropdown list as desired and are selectable. However, once an item is selected, that item does **not** appear in the text box/selected item portion of the ComboBox

Comment: so the text isn't showing. suggestion: avoid this usage of contentcontrol and create a ViewModel instead. also please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it's not possible to bind a control to another control entierly

Comment: I appreciate the help. I do have a ViewModel however the scope of this is far beyond what I can post here. I could perhaps make a simple example to show the issue. Still, I'm confused as to the confusion. I can make this work with a UserControl and have done so in the past. I'm just curious as to why I can't get this to work exclusively with XAML. @Bijan I'm not binding one control to another - I'm just binding the Tag property from an item in an itemscontrol.

Comment: from what I understand, `ControlActivities` is the source of another combobox. which means each content control is used as a combobox item

Comment: @Bijan thanks so much for the help however it is clear that you either don't have enough experience to fully understand the question or I am failing miserably to adequately explain the question. `ControlActivities` is defined as an `x:Array` and is bound to the `ItemsSource` property of the ComboBox in question. You are correct, each item in the `ItemsSource ObservableCollection` will be a `ContentControl` whose Tag property I want to bind to the selected item text box of the ComboBox. And the desired Tag property for each content control in the list is clearly defined.

Comment: I understand the question. your last combobox source is bound to an array of controls, which I believe never works. you need to bind view to a model (VM) not a view.

Comment: @Bijan Ha! Perhaps it is I that do not understand. I see your subtle but important point. I wonder if I can work around this and still remain in pure XAML. May require some trickery like a different item template for each combobox item. Still, it is confusing that `DisplayMemberPath="Tag"` works as desired - which means it is essentially saying: whatever you are storing internally as an item, render it using this property. Should be able to do that with the selected item box also...